# How Apple manage @private var and @properties?

Tags: objective-c

I take for example the `UIButton` interface.

Here the first rows of `@private` definition :

```
  @private
    CFMutableDictionaryRef _contentLookup;
    UIEdgeInsets           _contentEdgeInsets;
    UIEdgeInsets           _titleEdgeInsets;
```

And here 2 of these ivar, that are defined as properties:

```
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentEdgeInsets; 
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsetstitleEdgeInsets;
```

However these 2 properties are not defined on the ivars i found in private method (which have suffix `_`).

I'm not sure to understand how could be implemented setter and getter for these 2 properties to refer to the private ivars.

And a second question... i used to create properties for ivar, thus,  if i have an `ivar FOO` i can create a `@property` for `FOO`. Is it a normal behavior create property for a non existing ivar ? (in this case `contentEdgeInsets` is not an attribute for this class... on the contrary `_contentEdgeInset` is defined in `@interface` and this's a valid ivar). Ok what i missed with this argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you @synthesize these properties you do so like

```
@synthesize contentEdgeInsets = _contentEdgeInsets;
            ^property name      ^iVar name
```

Check out the [Property Implementation Directives](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW14) section in the documentation.

Comment: Omg... i'm an idiot :P i never used these option and forget to think about that... but why define it as private.. and than permit public access. It sounds strange.

Comment: No your not an idiot :). The public access is through a property and provides encapsulation for the class. They could one day for instance get rid of the iVar make contentEdgeInsets @dynamic and it would never effect your code since you are accessing it through a property.

Comment: Ok, then is an approach similar to C++, define accessor method for private attributes.

Comment: Yup you are not directly accessing the private variable but calling a method. `view.contentEdgeInsets` == `[view contentEdgetInsets]` properties are just syntactical sugar. As well as defining the iVar that backs the property you can also define the getter and setter method as well.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a property will use the ivar whose name is the same as that of the property, but it's also possible to specify an ivar of a different name. Do this in your @synthesize statement in the class implementation.

In the modern runtime, used pretty much everywhere at this point, you don't actually have to declare the ivar at all -- if you synthesize accessors for a property and there's no matching ivar, the runtime will provide one.

Finally, properties with @dynamic rather than @synthesized accessors don't necessarily need an ivar at all -- you're providing the accessors in this case, so you're free to derive the value of the property however you like.